# "push" is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: ios, storyboard

'push' is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later.

This is the problem I faced...

[image]

How to connect the ViewController ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "**show**" instead of "**push**".

[image]

"**push**" & "**modal**" is deprecated in iOS 8.0 & later

Comment: and what is the alternative to hide the pushed controller. Previously it was PopViewController and popToRootViewController.

Answer (score 2):

'Push deprecated ' means the storyboard supports 'PUSH SEGUE' no more in ios8 in XCode6. Use 'SHOW' instead of 'PUSH'.

Select the segue in the outline view.

Open up the Attributes Inspector from the Utility pane.

Choose the "Show (e.g. Push)" option from the Segue drop down.

You can see the same issue here in this question:

Adaptive segue in storyboard Xcode 6. Is push deprecated?